# No START No PRNDL LIGHT after forcing shifter cable into drive

Tags: starting, mazda, mazda-6, shifter

2017 mazda 6 gt

The car was fine when parked for lunch when leaving car started but shifter was stift. Forced car. Into drive PRNDL LIGHTS disappeared shifter then seemed loose. I put it back into "park" I then turned off my car tried to start it again, wouldn't start. PLEASE HELP ME!!

Comment: Sometimes when stopped on an incline in Park it can be difficult to shift it out of Park because of the stress against the gears holding the vehicle on a hill. It's good to apply the parking brake first, and then shift to Park. When you start, shift it out of Park before releasing the parking brake. IOW the Park mode should be the *secondary* means of braking the car.

Answer (score 1):

Since you forced your shifter, it sounds like you broke it. More than likely you'll need to get it replaced. At a minimum, you'll need to take it to a mechanic and have them diagnose it.

**EDIT:** Because it is most likely broke when you forced it, the the transmission is most likely in some other gear besides park or neutral, which is why after you shut it off, it won't start again. Until you get it diagnosed/fixed, you'll probably want to use your parking brake to ensure it doesn't roll anywhere unexpectedly.